# Font Awesome not working in offline mode with jsp

Tags: css, jsp, netbeans

I have searched throughout many articles and i still doesn't know why it's not working on offline mode, when i import a cdn link of cdn instead of lib from fontawesome then it's working just fine

```
    <link href="css/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

p/s: the icon is not showing up, they are all blank +_+

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you include the actual font files themselves when you extract the Font Awesome zip into your web folder. Otherwise there's nothing for the CSS to use.

Comment: Yes i actually copy entire its folder and put it inside my project, somehow its not working on glassfish server

Comment: @ArturiaPendragon Try looking at the console of your browser, it should give more information as to what exactly is wrong here. For example `Failed to load resource:`

Answer (score 0):

First, in your Cache Manifest, put the actual names of the font files in the folder:

```
fa/css/font-awesome.css
fa/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
fa/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
fa/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
```

This will make sure the files are deployed with your app.

Next, have a look at font-awesome.css. Notice the file names are referenced like this:

```
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0')
```

The names do not match the names in the manifest, so the files are not found. You need to modify fontawesome.css: modifying the names in the Cache Manifest will not work. Remove the suffix in names in fontawesome.css to be like this:

```
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2')
```

Seems like a bit of a hole in the implementation of Cache Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the "free for web" version here: https://fontawesome.com/download
2. copy the whole extracted-folder and be sure to import the path to "YOUR_LOCAL_PATH/fontawesome-free-5.15.1-web/css/fontawesome.min.css"
3. put the correct version if different from "free-5.15.1-web"